# Setting exeption for promise causes abort call

Tags: c++, exception, promise

I have a throwing function:

```
void calculateValuesThrowing(std::promise<int>&& pr, int a, int b)
{
    try
    {
        auto timeout = std::chrono::seconds(5);
        logInfo("Calculating value...");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);
        if (a == b)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("a cannot equal b");
        }
        pr.set_value(a + b);
    }
    catch(std::exception& exc)
    {
        pr.set_exception(std::current_exception()); // ok, jump here right after the "throw" above
    }
}
```

and I call it like that:

somewhere in main() function:

```
try
{
    std::promise<int> promise;
    auto future = promise.get_future();
    std::thread th(calculateValuesThrowing, std::move(promise), 10, 10);
    auto result = future.get();
    th.join();
}
catch(std::exception& exc)
{
    std::cout << "Error:" << exc.what(); // never get there
}
```

I expect an exception of *calculateValuesThrowing* will be "rethrown" so that I could process it in main's catch(), but right after *calculateValuesThrowing* finishes working I get *abort()*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `future.get()` throws, `th.join()` is never invoked so `th` goes out of scope while the thread is still active. [This terminates the program](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Try *[sic]* something like this instead:

```
std::promise<int> promise;
auto future = promise.get_future();

std::thread th(calculateValuesThrowing, std::move(promise), 10, 10);
try
{
    auto result = future.get();
}
catch(std::exception& exc)
{
    std::cout << "Error:" << exc.what(); // never get there
}

th.join();
```

Of course, now you can't use `result` outside of the `try`, but that was the case anyway. I don't have enough information about how you use it to suggest a concrete fix for that.